# Odds and Evens With Lists and Displaying

Tags: python-3.x

I am running into some issues with my code, it's not done yet because I am stuck. Here's what I have to do
1. In a loop, ask the user for a number until they enter -1.
2. Check if the number is even or odd
If the number is even, add it to the evens list.
If the number is odd, add it to the odds list.
3. Print how many even and odd numbers were given.
4. Print all the even numbers on the same line.
5. Print all the odd numbers on the same line

Here's what I have I done:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
number = [ ]
while num != -1:
    nums = input("Enter a number: ")
    number.append(nums)        
if nums == -1:
    if nums %2:`enter code here`
        print("This is an odd number")
    else:
        print("This is an even number")
```

When you type in "-1" nothing happens

Comment: Right. Because your loop has the condition `num != -1`...

Comment: I'm trying to state that in my loop if num doesn't -1 keep asking until -1 occurs but even then my If statement doesn't get kicked in

Comment: Your indentation is definitely off. Is the if-statement suppose to be inside the "while" loop?

Comment: You need to show us how you are running your code, also. What exactly do you mean "when you type in "-1" *nothing* happens"?

Comment: num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
number = []
e = []
o = []

while num != -1:
    nums = input("Enter a number: ")
    number.append(nums)        
    if nums.format(2):
        e.append(nums)
    else:
        o.append(nums)
    if nums == -1:
        print("You entered " + str(e) + "even numbers and " + str(o) + "odd numbers.")
        print("The even numbers are: ")
        print(str(e))
        print("The odd numbers are: ")
        print(str(o))